# Generating URL without website scope

Tags: url, redirect, base-url, geturl, multi-website

The main entry point of our webshop is `shop.com/dashboard`. When I want to redirect to this page, I use `Mage::getUrl('dashboard')` and it works fine. However, when in a specific website (E.g.: `shop.com/branded-shop`), `Mage::getUrl('dashboard')` returns `shop.com/branded-shop/dashboard`. Same goes for login/register/account/... links. How can I generate a link using Magento's getUrl methods, that always points me too `/dashboard`, so without the website folder (branded-shop)?

Comment: What is branded-shop a store or website? Please explain your magento installation.

Comment: branded-shop is folder containing an index.php where $runCode = 'branded_shop' and $runType = 'website'... Base URLs are set accordingly in the config for this website...